# Is it possible to remove updates from location manager on button click?

Tags: android, android-location

I want to remove location updates when the user presses a button. The class is implements a locationlistener like this

`public class Begin_Run_Map extends MapActivity implements LocationListener`

and later on in the code the onLocationChange method is implemented as well as the locationmanager requesting updates like so
`locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, this);`

I have tried to use `locMan.removeUpdates(this);` and `locMan.removeUpdates(Begin_Run_Map.this);`

Neither work, is it possible to do this?